# Disable built-in display when using external monitor on Wayland (Ubuntu 21.10)

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, thinkpad, wayland

I am running Ubuntu 21.10 on Wayland and have noticed that the built-in monitor of my ThinkPad Carbon X1 5th Gen (2017) is still drawing power, even when it is switched off and the display mode is set to "Single Display" on an external monitor. I used `powertop` to check power consumption and it shows that `Display backlight` still draws between 100mW and 1W.

What I am looking for is a way to completely switch off the built-in display, similar to the xorg `xset dpms force off` command. I have been searching around, but could not find a working solution to this problem yet. Is this possible on Wayland?